# How to show that $\int_0^1 dx \frac{1+x^a}{(1+x)^{a+2}} = \frac{1}{a+1}$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

From numerical evidence it appears that whenever the integral converges, $$J_a :=\int_0^1 dx \frac{1+x^a}{(1+x)^{a+2}} = \frac{1}{a+1}.$$
For $a \in \mathbb{N}$, I was able to prove this using induction (see below). How can we prove it for non-integer $a$?

> Integrating by parts,
>   $$\begin{align}
> J_n &= \left.-\frac{1}{n+1} \frac{1+x^n}{(1+x)^{n+1}}\right\lvert_0^1+ \frac{n}{n+1} \int_0^1 dx \frac{x^{n-1}}{(1+x)^{n+1}}
> \\&=\frac{1}{n+1}\left(1-2^{-n} \right) + \frac{n}{n+1} \int_0^1 dx \left[ \frac{1+x^{n-1}}{(1+x)^{n+1}} - \frac{1}{(1+x)^{n+1}} \right]
> \\&=\frac{n}{n+1}J_{n-1} + \frac{1}{n+1} \left[\left(1-2^{-n} \right) -\int_0^1 dx \frac{n}{(1+x)^{n+1}} \right]
> \\&=\frac{n}{n+1}J_{n-1}.
> \end{align}.
> $$
>   Because $J_0 = 1$, we therefore have $$J_n = \frac{1}{n+1}  \mathrm{for\,} n \in \mathbb{N}.$$

Comment: $B(x,y) = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{t^{x-1}+t^{y-1}}{(1+t)^{x+y}} \ dt$

Comment: A [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/985354).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1+x^{a}}{\left(1+x\right)^{a+2}}dx
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\left(1+x\right)^{a+2}}dx+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{a}}{\left(1+x\right)^{a+2}}dx \\
&=\left.-\frac{1+x}{\left(a+1\right)\left(1+x\right)^{a+2}}\right|_{0}^{1}+\left.\frac{\left(1+x\right)x^{a+1}}{\left(a+1\right)\left(1+x\right)^{a+2}}\right|_{0}^{1} \\
&=\frac{1}{a+1}.
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 5):

In general, an integral representation of the beta function is $$B(x,y) = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{t^{x-1} + t^{y-1}}{(1+t)^{x+y}} \ dt \ , \ \text{Re} (x), \text{Re}(y) >0 . $$

This can be derived by expressing the more well-known integral representation $$ B(x,y) = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{x-1}}{(1+t)^{x+y}} \ dt \tag{1}$$ as

$$\begin{align} B(x,y) &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{x-1}+t^{y-1}}{(1+t)^{x+y}} \ dt  \\ &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1}  \frac{t^{x-1}+t^{y-1}}{(1+t)^{x+y}} \ dt + \frac{1}{2} \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{t^{x-1}+t^{y-1}}{(1+t)^{x+y}} \ dt \end{align}$$

and then making the substitution $t = \frac{1}{u}$ in the second integral to get that

$$ \begin{align} B(x,y) &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1}  \frac{t^{x-1}+t^{y-1}}{(1+t)^{x+y}} \ dt + \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{u^{y-1}+u^{x-1}}{(u+1)^{x+y}} \ du \\ &= \int_{0}^{1}  \frac{t^{x-1}+t^{y-1}}{(1+t)^{x+y}} \ dt. \end{align}$$

Therefore,

$$ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1+x^{a}}{(1+x)^{a+2}} \ dx = B(1,a+1) = \frac{\Gamma(a+1)}{\Gamma(a+2)} = \frac{1}{a+1}.$$

$ $

$(1)$ http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BetaFunction.html (22)